# JSON-output formats in REST

Tags: json, restful-url

I have a structure similar to this, that is returned by a REST Api:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "A",
    "name": "blah, blah"
}
```

The natural output sample is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "A",
        "name": "blah, blah"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "A",
        "name": "blah, blah"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "B",
        "name": "blah, blah"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "C",
        "name": "blah, blah"
    }
]
```

For convenience, I would rather have the outout in the grouped format (around the "type"), like this:

```
{
    "A": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "blah, blah"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "blah, blah"
        }
    ],
    "B": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "B",
            "name": "blah, blah"
        }
    ],
    "C": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "C",
            "name": "blah, blah"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a common, REST-friendly way to do this in terms of input parameters?

I've though of a parameter "response_mode" which could be FLAT or GROUPED, but am not sure if it is ok from the RESTful viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

In php I would sort it like so:

```
<?php

$response = '[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "A",
        "name": "blah, blah"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "A",
        "name": "blah, blah"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "B",
        "name": "blah, blah"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "C",
        "name": "blah, blah"
    }
]';

$jsonDecoded = json_decode($response);
$newResponse = array();

foreach($jsonDecoded as $jd) {
   $newResponse[$jd->type][] = array(
      "id"   => $jd->id,
      "type" => $jd->type,
      "name" => $jd->name
   );
}

echo json_encode($newResponse);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that's not what I've asked. The question is not HOW to do it, but rather is it REST-friendly. Actually the question is not clear, I'll fix it.

Comment: ah, sorry for the misunderstanding. As far as params, if it were me, I would allow for ?groupBy=type in the url to output that formatting.